# Postgres database not starting on port 5432 despite no interfering process, but works on other ports

Tags: postgresql, local-database, postgres.app

### Problem

When I tried to turn on Postgres 15 database via Postgres.app on Port 5432 specifically, it doesn't work and won't turn on. I've tried everything in my power to resolve this but I can't seem to figure this out.

[This is the fail pop-up that comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BI4c.png) and I'm getting this error in the server log:

```
2023-04-19 00:10:05.163 PDT [35503] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-04-19 00:10:05.163 PDT [35503] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-04-19 00:10:05.163 PDT [35503] LOG:  could not bind Unix address "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432": Address already in use
2023-04-19 00:10:05.163 PDT [35503] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?
2023-04-19 00:10:05.163 PDT [35503] WARNING:  could not create Unix-domain socket in directory "/tmp"
2023-04-19 00:10:05.163 PDT [35503] FATAL:  could not create any Unix-domain sockets
2023-04-19 00:10:05.164 PDT [35503] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Note: I did not install Postgres via Homebrew and the database starts just fine if I choose another port like 5433.

### What I Did

I know what you're thinking, do I have a process running on Port 5432?

I checked that with `lsof -i :5432` and `sudo lsof -i :5432` and `netstat | grep "5432" | grep "LISTEN"` on port 5432, and the Terminal came up empty. I expected the interfering process to show up in the list of processes and then I was just going to kill that process to free up the port. However, there were literally no processes showing up on Port 5432.

I even attempted to uninstall and reinstall Postgres.app and Postgres and that still didn't resolve it (unless I somehow did that wrong). Kinda going crazy trying to solve this, been Googling and trying everything I can. Other port numbers are working, just not Port 5432. Also, I have no sensitive data to keep or save, I'm just trying to get my local Postgres to work on 5432 because I'd rather not have to change everything to 5433 or something whenever I use Postgres via codebase. So if there are some hacky ways to get this work that involves deleting stuff, I'm down.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Error messages don't lie

Comment: Not very helpful, sir :-|

Comment: What I mean is that there is definitely something conflicting. Could it be a previously bad shutdown that has left the unix socket in place (the `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` file mentioned in the error message). You could try deleting that if you can

Comment: None of the commands you showed us will indicate whether the file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 already exists.

Comment: I see! I couldn't find much information about what `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` was or what purpose it served (must've not Googled well enough ). Thank you for the help jjanes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the messages, there is no problem binding the TCP socket to port 5432. The problem is with creating the domain socket file, because there is already a file `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`. Remove that file, and the server should start.

Comment: Well, the hint did say `HINT: Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?`, which is why I was thinking in that direction, and I've never understood what `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` is about, so I'll definitely look into that!

Comment: It worked! Ran `ls -a` under `/tmp` and found the file and then ran `sudo rm .s.PGSQL.5432` to remove it. Thank you!

Comment: for me i removed the /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock file but forgot to remove /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 file that causes this error